# Why does `postgres` require a shell?

Tags: shell, postgresql, accounts

In my Debian *Wheezy* systems, I noticed that the postgres user 'postgres', the "PostgreSQL administrator", uses `/bin/bash` as shell.
However, I cannot figure out why this is needed.  Changing this to `/bin/false` still allows me to use the command `psql`.

So, why does the system user `postgres` require a shell, and does it have to be specifically `/bin/bash`?

Comment: This was required for the cronjob running `pg_autovacuum`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out [Why does the 'bin' user need a login shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28888/why-does-the-bin-user-need-a-login-shell/28900#28900)

It says this pattern for system users is

- Common in Debian, and not so much in other distributions.
- Considered a bug / genuine security issue by several people.
- Required in order to run cron jobs as that user, and perhaps also by some scripts if they use su -c to run as this user.  It should be easy to check for these.  Check for cron jobs belonging to psql.  Check for scripts in the postgres package (`dpkg-query -L`) and grep them for use of `su`.

It's also suggested that if your main worry is some sort of abuse of this user involving SSH logins, it might be convenient to use AllowGroups in sshd_config.  (Creating an `sshlogin` group, as recommended by the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/serverguide/user-management.html#other-security-considerations)).

The pattern was fixed in the base system earlier this year - see [bug #274229](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=274229).  So if you think postgres could be fixed as well, it would be great to contact the package maintainers e.g. by filing a bug.